# Normal map bake is not seamless after UV unwrapping character

Tags: uv, texture-baking, baking, uv-image-editor, normal-map

So I UV unwrapped my character first, then I duplicated it to use as a cage, I went on sculpting n inflated the cage mesh a bit, so it doesn't intercept with the high res sculpt that I want to extract normals from, then I bake normals and this is the result:

[image]

If, however, I don't unwrap the low res mesh then it kind of works better, but there are still glitches. So really what's the correct process here ?

Thanks !

Comment: hello please share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Bake and read your normal map as non-color data.

Comment: Yeah I just realized that one was about to delete this post but I'll leave it in case others do the same mistake... THANKS !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When setting the normal map texture it needs to be set as non colour data before bake